Gurobi Pool Search Mode outputs same Solutions multiple times
I am currently working on lineplanning problems (linear progamming), f.e. described in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225218930_Models_for_Line_Planning_in_Public_Transport.
I tried to implement a version that creates a (weightend) sum of direct travlers and costs in Python and tried to solve it via Gurobi. For further applications I want to check all feasable solutions for this problem via Gurobi Pool Search: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/poolsearchmode.html. The code solves the optimal solution and also gives out the correct line plan, but doesnt find all feasable solutions and their respective combined_obj values and rather outputs same solutions multiple times. I am not sure how easy it is to understand the code and/or find the mistake here.
This is my code:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        raise ConfigNoFileNameGivenException()
    logger.info("Start reading configuration")
    config = ConfigReader.read(sys.argv[1])
    #parameters = SolverParameters(config, "lc_")
    parameters = DirectParameters(config)

    logger.info("Finished reading configuration")

    logger.info("Begin reading input data")
    ptn = PTNReader.read(read_loads=True)
    od = DictOD()
    #od = ODReader.read(od)


    ods = ODReader.readMultiple(od)
    logger.info(f"Read in {len(ods)} OD matrices")
    logger.info("Finished reading input data")

    for index_of_od_matrix,od in enumerate(ods):


        logger.info(f"Begin execution of robust multicrieteria line planning model for OD-Matrix {index_of_od_matrix}")
        line_pool = LineReader.read(ptn, read_frequencies=False)
        solver = Solver.createSolver(parameters.getSolverType())
        model = solver.createModel()
        logger.debug("Add variables")
        # ToDo: add variables
        frequencies = {}
        for line in line_pool.getLines():
            frequency = model.addVariable(0, float('inf'), VariableType.INTEGER, name=f"f_{line.getId()}")
            frequencies[line] = frequency

        acceptableLineIds = compute_acceptable_line_ids(line_pool, compute_shortest_paths(ptn, od, parameters), ptn)

        d = {}
        for origin in ptn.getNodes():
            d[origin.getId()] = {}
            for destination in ptn.getNodes():
                d[origin.getId()][destination.getId()] = {}
                sumOfAllVariablesPerODPair = None
                if origin == destination or od.getValue(origin.getId(), destination.getId()) == 0:
                    continue
                for lineId in acceptableLineIds[(origin.getId(), destination.getId())]:
                    d[origin.getId()][destination.getId()][lineId] = model.addVariable(0, od.getValue(origin.getId(),
                                                                                                      destination.getId()),
                                                                                       VariableType.INTEGER,
                                                                                       name=f"d{origin.getId()}{destination.getId()}{lineId}")
                    if sumOfAllVariablesPerODPair is None:
                        sumOfAllVariablesPerODPair = d[origin.getId()][destination.getId()][lineId]
                    else:
                        sumOfAllVariablesPerODPair += d[origin.getId()][destination.getId()][lineId]

                if not sumOfAllVariablesPerODPair:
                    sumOfAllVariablesPerODPair = 0

                model.addConstraint(sumOfAllVariablesPerODPair, ConstraintSense.LESS_EQUAL,
                                    od.getValue(origin.getId(), destination.getId()),
                                    name=f"od_constraint{origin.getId()}_{destination.getId()}")

        logger.debug("Adding more constraints")
        # ToDo: add constraints
        for link in ptn.getEdges():
            sum_freq_per_line = model.createExpression()
            for line in line_pool.getLines():
                if link in line.getLinePath().getEdges():
                    sum_freq_per_line.add(frequencies[line])
            model.addConstraint(sum_freq_per_line, ConstraintSense.LESS_EQUAL, link.getUpperFrequencyBound(),
                                f"u_{link.getId()}")
            model.addConstraint(sum_freq_per_line, ConstraintSense.GREATER_EQUAL, link.getLowerFrequencyBound(),
                                f"l_{link.getId()}")

        logger.debug("Add capacity constraints")
        # Constraint 3.7 -> Ensure that the capacity of each line is not exceeded
        capacity = parameters.get_capacity()
        for link in ptn.getEdges():
            direct_travellers_on_line_and_edge = {}
            for line in line_pool.getLines():
                if link not in line.getLinePath().getEdges():
                    continue
                for origin in ptn.getNodes():
                    for destination in ptn.getNodes():
                        if origin == destination or od.getValue(origin.getId(), destination.getId()) == 0:
                            continue
                        od_pair = (origin.getId(), destination.getId())
                        if line.getId() not in acceptableLineIds.get(od_pair):
                            continue
                        if link not in acceptableLineIds.get(od_pair).get(line.getId()).getEdges():
                            continue

                        if line.getId() not in direct_travellers_on_line_and_edge:
                            direct_travellers_on_line_and_edge[line.getId()] = model.createExpression()
                        direct_travellers_on_line_and_edge[line.getId()].multiAdd(1,
                                                                                  d.get(origin.getId()).get(
                                                                                      destination.getId()).get(
                                                                                      line.getId()))
                capacity_of_line = model.createExpression()
                capacity_of_line.multiAdd(capacity, frequencies.get(line))
                # There may be a line that is not acceptable for anybody
                direct_travellers_on_line = direct_travellers_on_line_and_edge.get(line.getId())
                if direct_travellers_on_line is not None:
                    model.addConstraint(direct_travellers_on_line, ConstraintSense.LESS_EQUAL, capacity_of_line,
                                        "capacity_constraint_" + str(link.getId()) + "_" + str(line.getId()))

        logger.debug("Add parameters")
        parameters.setSolverParameters(model)
        # model.setSense(OptimizationSense.MINIMIZE)

        #objectives = list()
        model.getObjective().clear()
        obj = None
        for line, frequency in frequencies.items():
            if obj is None:
                obj = line.getCost() * frequency
            else:
                obj += line.getCost() * frequency

        #objectives.append(obj)

        obj2 = None
        for origin, destinations in d.items():
            for destination, lines in destinations.items():
                for line, variable in lines.items():
                    if obj2 is None:
                        obj2 = variable
                    else:
                        obj2 += variable

        #objectives.append(obj2)
        if obj2:
            combined_obj = obj - obj2
        else:
            combined_obj = obj

I tried to output all parameters of feasable solutions, but couldnt find any differences in the output data. All direct tavlers and costs are identical aswell as the final combined_obj value. I think it has to do with the constraints I am giving, since they dont allow a specific assignment for the direct travlers?
-> Maybe there is a workaround for Gurobi to only output same results with equal given parameters only once?

It is very unlikely you will be able to find all feasible solutions in practice.  You would need to set Symmetry=0 and DualReductions=0 to give it a fighting chance as these features will remove feasible solutions if enabled.

I don't think I have seen that behavior. I suggest making a reproducible example and talk to the Guobi people (https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us).
